# suhosin class method whitelist

Tags: php, suhosin

I'm hardening a nginx webserver. I'm using suhosin to harden php language, but in simulation mode it complains about `addserver()` method of `Memcache` class even if I added it to `suhosin.executor.func.whitelist`

**The log reports:**

> 2016/03/25 22:50:15 [error] 2720#0: *37 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  SIMULATION - addserver() has been disabled for security reasons in /var/www/bla bla bla

Whitelist is:

```
rand,trim,urldecode,filter_var,addserver
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you restart the server?